# Merge two dataframes by row/column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data-frames with identical columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["B2", "B3", "B6", "B7"],
    "B": ["D2", "D3", "D6", "D7"],
    "C": ["F2", "F3", "F6", "F7"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": ["A2", "A3", "A6", "A7"],
        "B": ["E2", "E3", "E6", "E7"],
        "C": ["Z2", "Z3", "Z6", "Z7"]})
```

I am trying to find a way to combine the two DFs in a new data-frame, wherein each cell combines the strings from the equivalent positions in `df1` and `df2`; for example, column A at index position 0 would be the string "B2A2". The resulting data-frame would look something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
     A           B           C
-----------------------------------
  "B2A2"       "D2E2"      "F2Z2"
  "B3A3"       "D3E3"      "F3Z3"
  "B6A6"       "D6E6"      "F6Z6"
  "B7A7"       "D7E7"      "F7Z7"
-----------------------------------
```

I have tried looking at the Pandas documentation for `merge`  and `concat`, but neither seem to do what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean

```
df1 + df2
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0  B2A2  D2E2  F2Z2
1  B3A3  D3E3  F3Z3
2  B6A6  D6E6  F6Z6
3  B7A7  D7E7  F7Z7
```

Comment: Feel rather foolish but yes, that's exactly what I needed!!